# roid.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Anyone able to help me solve why I am not able to run the app past its inital loading? If I click on the hourly or daily forecast they both crash out. Here

```
    07-16 20:06:27.272    2191-2191/com.dredaydesigns.stormy E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.dredaydesigns.stormy, PID: 2191
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dredaydesigns.stormy/com.dredaydesigns.stormy.ui.HourlyForecastActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class RecyclerView
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class RecyclerView
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
                at com.dredaydesigns.stormy.ui.HourlyForecastActivity.onCreate(HourlyForecastActivity.java:31)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dredaydesigns.stormy-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.dredaydesigns.stormy-2, /system/lib]]
                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)


 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.dredaydesigns.stormy.ui.HourlyForecastActivity.onCreate(HourlyForecastActivity.java:31)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my HourlyForecastAdapter.

```
package com.dredaydesigns.stormy.ui;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.dredaydesigns.stormy.R;
import com.dredaydesigns.stormy.adapters.HourAdapter;
import com.dredaydesigns.stormy.weather.Hour;

import java.util.Arrays;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;

public class HourlyForecastActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Hour[] mHours;

    @InjectView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hourly_forecast);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MainActivity.HOURLY_FORECAST);
        mHours = Arrays.copyOf(parcelables, parcelables.length, Hour[].class);


        HourAdapter adapter = new HourAdapter(this, mHours);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    }


}
```

Here is my houradapter.java.

```
 package com.dredaydesigns.stormy.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dredaydesigns.stormy.R;
import com.dredaydesigns.stormy.weather.Hour;

/**
 * Created by Andreas on 7/2/2015.
 */
public class HourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <HourAdapter.HourViewHolder> {
    private Hour [] mHours;
    private Context mContext;

    public HourAdapter(Context context,Hour [] hours) {
        mHours = hours;
    }

    @Override
    public HourViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.hourly_list_item, parent, false);
        HourViewHolder viewHolder = new HourViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HourViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindHour(mHours[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mHours.length;
    }


    public class HourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView mTimeLabel;
        public TextView mSummaryLabel;
        public TextView mTemperatureLabel;
        public ImageView mIconImageView;

        public HourViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTimeLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeLabel);
            mSummaryLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.summaryLabel);
            mTemperatureLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.temperatureLabel);
            mIconImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
        }
        public void bindHour(Hour hour) {

        mTimeLabel.setText(hour.getHour());
        mSummaryLabel.setText(hour.getSummary());
        mTemperatureLabel.setText(hour.getTemperature() + "");


           mIconImageView.setImageResource(hour.getIconId());


        }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String time = mTimeLabel.getText() + "";
                String temp = mTemperatureLabel.getText() +"";
                String summary = mSummaryLabel.getText().toString();
                String message = String.format("At %s it will be %s and %s.", time, temp, summary);
                Toast.makeText(mContext,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using RecycleView tag in your layour incorrect.
You write like this `<RecycleView ...`, but you need to write `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>`

All views you are using in xml, inflater looking at android.view package. So you have exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.RecyclerView"
```

Because RecyclerView class is located in android.suport.v7.widget package. In cases like this, you need to use full qualified name of view class.